# how to apply a timelimit to series of callback functions

Tags: node.js

How would you go about applying a time limit to a series of callbacks in node.js?

Would this be easier using the async library?

Thankyou, as you can see I'm struggling with asynchronous javascript.

Comment: I understand you have a task you would complete with a chain of callback functions, but in case this takes too long, you want to back out and do some clean-up. Right?

Comment: Thanks Dirk, Yes thats what Im looking at

Comment: I would write a function accepting a nextStep function, a timeOut instant and a backOut function. Each next step would call the next next step passing the same timeOut instant. The backOut from the next step should extend that of the previous one.

Comment: Hi Dirk, would you consider adding in a small code example, to illustrate the timeouts a bit more, thanks heaps

Comment: Within 30 hours I will

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling the next step directly, call the below function with
**doNext** : your actual next step 
**stepData** : your parameters plus an execution time limit in miliseconds
**unDoThis** : the function to run if the work just done ever must be undone

```
function nextStep(doNext, stepData, unDoThis) {
```

The first time, set the time out

```
    if (!stepData.expireAt) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        stepData.expireAt = currentDate.setMilliseconds(currentDate.getMilliseconds() + stepData.runMiliseconds);
        console.log(new Date().toISOString() +" We will expire at " 
                + new Date(stepData.expireAt).toISOString());
    };
```

Remember how to undo the last completed step

```
    if (!stepData.unDoAll) stepData.unDoAll = [];
    if (unDoThis) stepData.unDoAll.push(unDoThis);
```

If time is expired, undo all completed steps

```
    if (new Date(stepData.expireAt) < new Date().getTime()) {
        while (stepData.unDoAll.length) {
            var unDoOne = stepData.unDoAll.pop();
            unDoOne();
        }
        console.log(new Date().toISOString() +' That was it!');
```

else perform the next step

```
    } else {
        doNext(stepData, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 2));
    }
}
```

From the below worker functions we will build the chain that we will interupt

```
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function oneStep(stepData) {
    console.log (new Date().toISOString() +' ('+ stepData.nrIterations +') I do some stuff ');
    sleep(100);

    var myIteration = stepData.nrIterations--;
    if (stepData.nrIterations) {
        nextStep(otherStep, stepData);
    }
}

function otherStep(stepData) {
    console.log (new Date().toISOString() +' ('+ stepData.nrIterations +') I do more stuff, leaving a trace');
    sleep(100);

    var myIteration = stepData.nrIterations--;
    if (stepData.nrIterations) {
        nextStep(oneStep, stepData, function () {
            console.log(new Date().toISOString() +' ('+ myIteration +') I clean some trace ');
        });
    }
}
```

And now we use it.
Play around with runMiliseconds and nrIterations to see the effect

```
console.log (new Date().toISOString() + ' About to start ');
var currentDate = new Date();
nextStep(oneStep, {
    runMiliseconds : 250, 
    nrIterations: 22
});
```